# Issue with upgrade to bootstrap-sass 3.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, bootstrap-sass

Is there something else that needs to be referenced/configured when upgrading the bootstrap-sass gem to `~> 3.2.0`?

Using RubyMine 6.3 as the editor and the following in the Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.1.2'  
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'  
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'  
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.1'
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss will be happy with

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

*However*, once the bootstrap-sass gem is upgraded to its current version by changing the Gemfile reference to (and then running bundle update):

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

RubyMine now has issues the `@import 'bootstrap';` statement, saying *"Cannot resolve import into sass/scss file"*.

The twbs/bootstrap-sass installation docs don't seem to infer that anything else is needed...

Comment: Is `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` included in the manifest? Also restarting the server may solve this issue if you haven't done so already. Seems to be an issue with SCSS file, not the gem.

Comment: Thanks for the input @dayna. Server isn't running. Reopened the project though in case RubyMine was not triggering a 'rescan' after the `bundle update`. Issue occurs upon changing gem version from `3.1.1.1` to `~> 3.2.0`.

Comment: @Karl - I have the same issue in RM 6.3.3 and have no issues with bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1. After a bit of digging, I learned that bootstrap-sass 3.2.0 moved the asset directory from vendor/assets to assets/. RM is not able to read/import the scss and js files from this location. I went back to 3.1.1.1 for now but did open a ticket with JetBrains in the hopes they can address the issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15585

Comment: Any word back on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables.