# Ran a bundle install, bootstrap updated, now I'm getting routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was just fiddling around with some things and happened to run bundle install on my ruby on rails app. I noticed that bootstrap updated from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0 and now when I go to generate certain views, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"):
```

Didn't happen until this gem update. Any suggestions? I've tried explicitly using 3.1.1 in the Gemfile and running bundle again, but this doesn't help.  It looks just like a simple routing issue, but idk why this would have only changed during the gem update.

Answer (score 8):

My problem was with the order I was importing bootstrap in my application.css.scss file.  Make sure the order goes:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: this hasn't helped me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who else can't get an answer on this, I manually changed this file:

/home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.2/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss and took out the $icon_path or whatever it was and replaced it with "../assets/bootstrap/

Fixed the problem thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like you. After some research these are the most important things i found out:

1) Since bootstrap-sass version 3.2.0 the asset directory moved from **vendor/assets** to **assets/**
source: [Issue with upgrade to bootstrap-sass 3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939189/issue-with-upgrade-to-bootstrap-sass-3-2-0)

2) The font files from customizer are probably corrupted and should be downloaded directly from the [Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).
source: [Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working)

As you already said; change the version back to 3.1.1.1 should do the trick. I uninstalled the gem via:

```
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass
```

Then I changed the version defined in the gemfile and reinstalled it with

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
bundle update
```

This might help people facing the same issue.